# Flutter: HttpClient post contentLength -- exception

Tags: flutter

Very weird...

In order to post some JSON data to my server, I define the contentLength to the length of the JSON encoded data but I then receive an exception that says "*Content size exceeds specified contentLength*".  Difference is 1 byte.

Here is the source code:

```
Future<Map> ajaxPost(String serviceName, Map data) async {
  var responseBody = json.decode('{"data": "", "status": "NOK"}');
  try {
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var uri = mid.serverHttps ? new Uri.https(mid.serverUrl, _serverApi + serviceName)
                              : new Uri.http(mid.serverUrl, _serverApi + serviceName);
    var request = await httpClient.postUrl(uri);
    var body = json.encode(data);

    request.headers
      ..add('X-mobile-uuid', await _getDeviceIdentity())
      ..add('X-mobile-token', await mid.getMobileToken());

    request.headers.contentLength = body.length;
    request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    request.write(body);

    var response = await request.close();
    if (response.statusCode == 200){
      responseBody = json.decode(await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join());

      //
      // If we receive a new token, let's save it
      //
      if (responseBody["status"] == "TOKEN"){
        await mid.setMobileToken(responseBody["data"]);

        // Let's change the status to "OK", to make it easier to handle
        responseBody["status"] = "OK";
      }
    }
  } catch(e){
    // An error was received
    throw new Exception("AJAX ERROR");
  }
  return responseBody;
}
```

Some other times, it works fine...

Am I doing anything wrong with this code?

Many thanks for your help.

**EDITED WITH SOLUTION**:

Many thanks for your help.  The simply fact of using `utf8.encode(json.encode(data))` did not fully work.  So, I turned to the **http** library and it now works like a charm.  The code is even lighter!

Here is the new version of the code:

```
Future<Map> ajaxPut(String serviceName, Map data) async {
  var responseBody = json.decode('{"data": "", "status": "NOK"}');
  try {
    var response = await http.put(mid.urlBase + '/$_serverApi$serviceName',
        body: json.encode(data),
        headers: {
          'X-mobile-uuid': await _getDeviceIdentity(),
          'X-mobile-token': await mid.getMobileToken(),
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      responseBody = json.decode(response.body);

      //
      // If we receive a new token, let's save it
      //
      if (responseBody["status"] == "TOKEN") {
        await mid.setMobileToken(responseBody["data"]);

        // Let's change the status to "OK", to make it easier to handle
        responseBody["status"] = "OK";
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // An error was received
    throw new Exception("AJAX ERROR");
  }
  return responseBody;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Günter is right. Content-Length has to be the length of the byte array after encoding from a String to bytes in whatever encoding you server requires.

There's a package called [http](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) which provides a slightly higher level api (it uses dart.io httpClient under the hood) which takes care of encoding the post body and length for you. For example, when you need to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form it will even take a Map and do all the encoding for you (you still need to encode to json yourself). It's equally happy to send just a `String` or `List<int>`. Here's an example:

```
  Map<String, String> body = {
    'name': 'doodle',
    'color': 'blue',
    'teamJson': json.encode({
      'homeTeam': {'team': 'Team A'},
      'awayTeam': {'team': 'Team B'},
    }),
  };

  Response r = await post(
    url,
    body: body,
  );
```

Answer (score 6):

I got it working with

`req.headers.contentLength = utf8.encode(body).length;`

From an indirect tip of the [Utf8Codec](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-convert/Utf8Codec-class.html) documentation which states

> decode(List codeUnits, { bool allowMalformed }) → String
>
> Decodes the UTF-8 codeUnits (a list of unsigned 8-bit integers) to the corresponding string.

That means that`utf8.encode()` returns `codeUnits` which actually means `List<uint8>`.

Encoding a String payload would in theory return a list which length is the length of the payload in bytes.

So using `httpClient` means to always measure the length of the payload in **bytes**, not the length of a String which may differ.

Answer (score 3):

Seems your string contains multibyte characters.
UTF8-encode the string to get the correct length:

```
var body = utf8.encode(json.encode(data));
```