# How to calculate Content-Length of a request body of a Http Post Request

Tags: java, flutter, http, post, httprequest

I am trying to calculate the Content-Length of the request body of a http post request but I keep getting error that indicated wrong Content-Length. Request body looks like following:

```
Map<String, String> body = {
  'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
  'client_id': 'clientid',
  'code': authCode,
  'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8080/login/callback',
  'code_verifier':
      'codeverifier',
};
```

I tried couple solutions like concatenating content of the body into one string such as following and then convert it into byte array and send the length of it but it didn't work.

```
String bodyStr = "grant_type:authorization_code" +
    "client_id:clientid" +
    "code:{$authCode}" +
    "redirect_uri:http://localhost:8080/login/callback" +
    "code_verifier:codeverifier";
    List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(bodyStr);
```

The post request body is x-www-form-urlencoded format and content length has to be calculated correctly. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to calculate it manually? Usually this is being done by the underlying used http library.

Comment: You may try one of those solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089550/flutter-httpclient-post-contentlength-exception

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Comment: Do you know any library that can calculate it ?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make a list of integer...

```
String bodyStr = "...";
byte[] bytes = bodyStr.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
int len = bytes.length;
response.setContentLength(len);
response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
```

This example is using the HttpServletResponse object from a HttpServlet.  Not sure if that's what you need.

I have used this a fair amount, it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I encapsulated it myself. Generally, I don't need to calculate it. Unless it's a special occasion.
Okhttp3 is recommended

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).